# Extending a message deadline "indefinitely"

Tags: c#, .net, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a worker attached to a subscription processing messages. Depending on the message payload, the worker could possibly take days to completely process the message.

I'm a bit confused by different properties that the client can set that control how the Pub/Sub client library automatically extends the deadline so that the worker can process the message without fearing that the message will be redelivered.

Properties from [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1/latest/Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1.SubscriberClient#properties) which is not very clear :

`MinimumAckDeadline`, `MaximumAckDeadline`, `DefaultAckDeadline`, `MinimumAckExtensionWindow`, `DefaultAckExtensionWindow`, `MinimumLeaseExtensionDelay`, and `DefaultMaxTotalAckExtension`

I believe I want to set `DefaultMaxTotalAckExtension` to a large value (several days) to allow my subscriber to continue working on the message without getting some kind of time out.

But I think I also want to modify the AckDeadline so that Pub/Sub knows that the client is still alive. Not sure which one I would want to modify: `MinimumAckDeadline`, `MaximumAckDeadline`, `DefaultAckDeadline`.

Aside from those properties, I don't know if I need to set `MinimumAckExtensionWindow`, `DefaultAckExtensionWindow`, or `MinimumLeaseExtensionDelay`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of the properties you mentioned are default/limit properties for the `SubscriberClient` class itself. Note that they are static only have getters, not setters. What you want to set is [`MaxTotalAckExtension`](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1/latest/Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1.SubscriberClient.Settings#Google_Cloud_PubSub_V1_SubscriberClient_Settings_MaxTotalAckExtension), which controls the maximum amount of time a message's lease will be extended.

However, taking days to process a message is considered an anti-pattern for Cloud Pub/Sub and will very likely result in duplicate deliveries. If you are going to take that long to process a message, you probably need to look at other options like persisting it locally (in a file or in a database), acking it, and then processing it. At that point, you may consider just writing directly to a database instead of to Pub/Sub and scanning for rows that need to be processed by your subscribers.